# Eclipse Deletes Texture Files

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

I have been using Java Eclipse to make a Minecraft mod and have placed my textures in my eclipse bin folder. When my computer restarted for windows updates, I rebooted eclipse and it had deleted my textures! I had spent the course of an hour or more detailing these textures and I am wondering if there is any way I can get them back.

Comment: How is that related to programming?

Comment: Also, why do you think that minecraft modding experts are better prepared to answer your question than anyone else? It's not like an IDE losing all textures is specific to minecraft.

Comment: For undeleting files that you accidentally delete, there's the recycling bin, the NTFS revision history, Recuva, ...

Comment: Why do you think it was Eclipse that deleted your texture files? Where did you store them?

Comment: I didn't delete them. When I opened eclipse, they were gone. During the booting of eclipse, it might have cleaned out the files. They were in the eclipse/Minecraft/bin folder, where mod textures are placed. And why did you quadruple post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right-clicking while in the folder and pressing "Properties." Then go to "Previous Versions" and try to find the files there.

*note*: Only works on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Don't place your textures in the bin folder, the files get re-created every time you compile. Place them in the src folder instead.